# rabbitMQ AlreadyClosedException when basicAck(knowledging)

Tags: grails, groovy, rabbitmq

My groovy code uses the Rabbit Native Plugin for grails:

```
def handleMessage(def body, MessageContext context) {
    // With noAck=false, messages must be acknowledged manually with basic.ack.
    boolean noAck = false
    // send Ack on true and nack on false
    if(processMessage(new SensorEvent(body))){
           context.channel.basicAck(context.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(),noAck)
    }else{
        context.channel.basicNack(context.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false, false);

    }
    return ''
}
```

If I comment out the two lines of code that do the Ack and Nack everything works fine.  If I uncomment the basicAck I get the following exception

```
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:195)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:309)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.transmit(AMQChannel.java:303)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicReject(ChannelN.java:1045)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareChannelN.basicReject(RecoveryAwareChannelN.java:72)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicReject(AutorecoveringChannel.java:354)
```

I've seen advice saying to use the Subscription.Ack().  There is no Subscription class in the Java/Groovy rabbitMQ.

Any idea why I'm getting the exception?

Edit: since I'm using the Native Plugin I needed to create a consumer that implemented the interface

```
def handleMessage(def body, MessageContext context)
```

The subscribing is handled with:

```
 /**
 * Consumer configuration.
 */
static rabbitConfig = [
        "queue": "my.queueName"
]
```

Comment: can you adjust the code sample to include the part where you are setting up the subscription and adding the callback for the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

> PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1,

Means that you are trying to ack a message on a different channel than the one which received said message. Delivery Tags are scoped per channel